# How to assign a return value from a function directly to an object literal

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

"myFunction" is an anonymous function that I have got as a parameter.
...

```
newObj = { id: idValue, div: null };
newObj.div = myFunction();
```

Is there a shorter way, a way to directly assign the result of a function to the object literal, something like:

```
newObj = { id: idValue, div: (myFunction ())};
```

Thanks alot in advance
Wolfgang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you have should work:

```
newObj = {id:idValue, div: myfunction()};
```

Comment: Hello James! Thank you for your answer. I had tried "...div: myfunction();}" (with a semicolon at the end) and this did not work. Wolfgang

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is a functional programming, which means that you can use `anonymous functions` almost everywhere. Consider this example:

```
var human = { firstName: 'Saeed', lastName: 'Neamati', getName: function () {
        return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    }
};
human.getName();
```

Here, an anonymous function is assigned to the `getName` attribute.
Now, in your example, two things are possible.

1. If you want to assign the **returned value** of the function to an attribute of the object (as you specified), then you should use:

   `newObj = {id:idValue, div: myfunction()};`
2. If you want to assign the **function**, not the **returned value** of the function to the attribute, then you should drop parantheses:

   `newObj = {id:idValue, div: myfunction};`

Comment: I don't think that you meant to use the term "functional programming", as that is something completely different. I think that what you meant to say is that functions are first class members in Javascript.