# passing json data to jQuery.post function

Tags: jquery, json, getelementbyid

i am going to try the jQuery code:

```
$.post("test.php", { category: "Ubuntu", newname: "Hash" },

function(data) {
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
   });
```

but in json data i want to use some data taken from a formfield. i used to grab the data using `getElementById('fieldname').value`. How to pass variable to json query ?

Comment: This is not JSON. Simply assign the value to one of the properties of the objects. Please read [Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) to learn the basics about objects (reading the whole guide is probably helpful as well).

Comment: Related: [How to assign a return value from a function directly to an object literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621655/how-to-assign-a-return-value-from-a-function-directly-to-an-object-literal).

Comment: thanks, this looks much more simple now.

Answer (score 1):

```
var category = $('#fieldname1').val(), // just assume id with fieldname1, fieldname2 etc
    newname =  $('#fieldname2').val();

$.post("test.php", { category:category , newname: newname  },

function(data) {
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

We can post anything in jquery as

```
var cat = $('#cat').val(),//for taking category value
    name =  $('#new').val();//for taking newname value
$.post("test.php", { category:cat , newname: name  },function(data) {
     alert("Data that came from server : " + data);
});
```

You can access the variables in server as **category** and **newname** as the variables. Access them and then **return** the data you want.Your **returned data** comes to the variable **data** of the callback **function()**.

Here we accessed the values of the **textboxes**  with id as **cat** and **new**.